# Android SharedPreferences don't seem to work

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a small game that I'm working on, and I'm just working on updating the score, but I can't get it to work properly.

Note: I cut pieces of my program to show here, I've got a whole bunch of other things that are being set, but they don't touch the "score" at all, that's why the code is a little *shorthand*.

**My Code:**

```
public class Start_Test extends Activity {

TextView total_points;
long new_total;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_three);
    total_points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        new_total = pref.getLong("total_points", 0);
        setTouchListener();
    updateTotal(0);


}

public void updateTotal(long change_in_points) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        new_total = new_total + change_in_points;
        pref.edit().putLong("total_points", new_total);
        pref.edit().commit();
        total_points.setText("" + new_total);

    }

public void setTouchListeners() {

        button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                updateTotal(25);
                return false;
            }

        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because you are creating a new shared preference Edit instance. ( as you call .edit() twice and commit an uneditted version)

Change your code...

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    new_total = new_total + change_in_points;
    pref.edit().putLong("total_points", new_total);
    pref.edit().commit();
```

To the following:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor pref = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    new_total = new_total + change_in_points;
    pref.putLong("total_points", new_total);
    pref.commit();
```

Comment: Ah. So simple. Can't believe I did that. I'll go rewrite all of my "put" statements. **EDIT:** just tried it. It worked! Thanks! 6 minutes until I can accept it. heh.

Comment: @EGHDK :p At least you know for next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Each call to .edit() creates a new Editor.

Change

```
pref.edit().putLong("total_points", new_total);
pref.edit().commit();
```

to

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putLong("total_points", new_total);
editor.commit();
```